# when talking about phonics, is this use of the word "sound" correct?

Tags: grammar, phonics

Sound is a verb, so you can say "the computer sounds the noise"
But can you say, "the letter K sounds kuh" and "what does the letter K sound?"

I understand you can say "what does K sound like, what is the sound of K, etc." but when trying to make that sentence as simple as possible, asking "what does the letter sound?" and "the Letter sounds __" seems grammatically correct, but doesn't feel like its correct. sounds very weird to me.

So is my sentence correct? and if it isn't, what would be the absolute simplest way to ask and answer that question.

Comment: A bit off topic, but as a teacher be sure not to add /uh/ to the end of letter sounds. Some students will add that sound in as they sound out the word. The word cat then sounds like "cuh-at". Just a teacher tip someone shared with me and I am passing it on to you.

Comment: Used as a verb, *sound* has the notion of "make something else produce a sound" - e.g. *sound the horn* = do something to the horn so that the horn makes a noise.

Comment: Please rephrase *Sound* is a verb, so you can say *the computer sounds the noise* and *the letter K sounds kuh* and *what does the letter K sound* so they mean something in English?

I understand you can say *what does K sound like; what is the sound of K, etc* but when trying to make that sentence simple, no: *what does the letter sound?* is and always will be simply wrong.

So no, your sentence is nothing like correct?